# Running a program with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start causes an Application Error

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

On my PC DWG files open with:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoCAD LT 2007\acadlt.exe" "%1"
```

If I run this from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoCAD LT 2007\acadlt.exe" "C:\Some Path\Test.dwg"
```

AutoCAD Lite open the DWG file.

Similarly if I open a command prompt and run the same exe with argument, it works fine.

However if I use

```
var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
```

and then

```
info.FileName = "C:\Some Path\Test.dwg";
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
```

or

```
info.FileName = "C:\Program Files\AutoCAD LT 2007\acadlt.exe";
info.Arguments= "C:\Some Path\Test.dwg"
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
```

or

```
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.Arguments= "C:\Program Files\AutoCAD LT 2007\acadlt.exe" "C:\Some Path\Test.dwg"
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
```

I get the following error:

---

### acadlt.exe - Application Error

The instruction at "0x01317c8c" referenced memory at "0x01317c8c". The memory could not be "read".

Click on OK to terminate the program
Click on CANCEL to debug the program

### OK   Cancel

---

Incidentally the code works ok if I step through the code with the debugger.

Anyone know how I can use Process.Start to open this DWG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was Xenocode Postbuild causing the Application Error. If I run the same code on a normal .NET exe (not obfuscated), it works fine. I have referred to Xenocode for a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to have the correct working folder specified:

```
info.WorkingDirectory = "same path as current directory in cmd.exe";
```

Comment: There isn't much of anything left.  I always hated acad.

Comment: This seems hard to get from code?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217951/get-the-current-working-directory-for-cmd-exe

Comment: If I set 
info.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\cmd.exe"; 
info.Arguments= "echo %CD%" 
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 

the current directory (CD) is the same as Environment.CurrentDirectory. 

However if I run cmd.exe from the command prompt, CD is something completely different

Comment: @Andrew Roberts: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my sample. You should use the same directory as when you start the process interactively from the console window.

Answer (score 2):

One difference between launching from the command line and using `ProcessStartInfo` in this manner is that the latter [uses shell execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx).  I don't think it's likely to be causing this problem but can cause issues.  Try adding the following and seeing if it fixes the problem.

```
info.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Comment: Isn't the command line/shell per-se using `ShellExecute`/`ShellExecuteEx` which would be identical to calling `Process.Start` with `UseShellExecute = true;`?

Comment: @0xA3 if it's being launched from cmd.exe I don't *believe* it uses shell execution.  The first example has an argument of `%1` which indicates a batch file of sorts and cmd.

Comment: The "%1" is just the syntax that Windows Explorer uses when displaying the settings in Registered File Types